Pending Payment Listener Status for “Slow test card, declines after a few minutes” RevenueCat flutter
I'm looking for support in the case below:
I'm working on RevenueCat for In app purchase on flutter.
I use ‘getCustomerInfo’, it works for:

“Test card, always approves” / “Slow test card, approves after a  few minutes” and “Test card, always declines” but for “Slow test card, declines after a few minutes”, there is no response status of that case.

This is the image of payment method.
Please check the sample code below:
Future<void> makePurchase(context, String numberOfEgg) async {
      Map<String, dynamic> payload = {};
      List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> filteredItems = [];
      bool slowCardApproval = true;
      try {
        filteredItems =
            filterById(numberOfEgg, Platform.isIOS ? products : googleProducts);

        if (filteredItems.isNotEmpty && !isPurchasePending) {
          ref.read(purchaseInProgressProvider.notifier).setInProgress(true);

          payload = {
            'identifier': filteredItems[0]['identifier'],
            'description': filteredItems[0]['description'],
            'title': filteredItems[0]['title'],
            'price': filteredItems[0]['price'],
            'priceString': filteredItems[0]['priceString'],
            'currencyCode': filteredItems[0]['currencyCode']
          };

          final payloadGooglePay = {
            'identifier': filteredItems[0]['identifier'],
            'description': filteredItems[0]['description'],
            'title': filteredItems[0]['title'],
            'price': filteredItems[0]['price'],
            'priceString': filteredItems[0]['priceString'],
            'currencyCode': filteredItems[0]['currencyCode'],
            'productCategory': 'NON_SUBSCRIPTION',
          };

          CustomerInfo customerInfo = await Purchases.purchaseStoreProduct(
              Platform.isIOS
                  ? StoreProduct.fromJson(payload)
                  : StoreProduct.fromJson(payloadGooglePay));
          // Check if the purchase is active
          if (customerInfo
              .entitlements
              .all[Platform.isIOS
                  ? dotenv.env['REVENUECAT_ENTITLEMENTS_APPLE']
                  : dotenv.env['REVENUECAT_ENTITLEMENTS_GOOGLE']]!
              .isActive) {
            isPurchasePending =
                false; // Set isPurchasePending to false when a purchase is confirmed
            ref
                .read(purchaseInProgressProvider.notifier)
                .setInProgress(false); // Add this line
            final titleValue = getTitlePurchase(payload['title']);
            final titleKoValue = getTitleKoPurchase(payload['title']);
            ref.read(bonusEggsHistoryProvider).memberBonusAttend(
                  memberId: memberInfo.id!,
                  bonusEggQty: int.parse(numberOfEgg),
                  type: 1,
                  title: titleValue,
                  titleKo: titleKoValue,
                );
            // Create a new instance of MemberModel with the updated purchasedEggs value
            if (memberInfo.id != null) {
              final updatedMemberInfo = memberInfo.copyWith(
                  purchasedEggs:
                      memberInfo.purchasedEggs! + int.parse(numberOfEgg));
              // Update memberInfo immediately after purchase is successful
              ref
                  .read(memberInfoProvider.notifier)
                  .updateState(updatedMemberInfo);
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => ChargeUseHistoryScreen(
                          purchasedEgg: filteredItems[0]['id'],
                          purchaseSuccessful: true,
                        )),
              ).then((value) => {
                    ref.refresh(memberObjByIdProvider(memberInfo.id)),
                    ref.refresh(memberObjByIdProvider(eggMember!.id)),
                    ref.refresh(memberObjProvider),
                    ref.refresh(memberInfoProvider),
                    ref.refresh(bonusEggsHistoryProvider),
                    ref.refresh(memberObjByIdProvider(memberInfo.id ?? 0)),
                    ref.refresh(usageEggHistoryFutureProvider(memberInfo.id!)),
                    ref.refresh(
                        purchasedEggHistoryFutureProvider(memberInfo.id!)),
                    ref.refresh(loadingProvider),
                  });
            }
            debugPrint('Purchase successful########################');
          }
        }
      } catch (e) {
        debugPrint('Purchase failed with error++++++++++++++++++: $e');

        if (e is PlatformException) {
          if (e.code == '3' || e.code == '1') {
            isPurchasePending = false;
            ref.read(purchaseInProgressProvider.notifier).setInProgress(false);
            slowCardApproval = false;
            Purchases.addCustomerInfoUpdateListener((customerInfo) async {
              var entitlements = customerInfo.entitlements.all;
              if (entitlements.isEmpty) {
                slowCardApproval = false;
              } else {
                var latestPurchaseDate =
                    entitlements.values.first.latestPurchaseDate;
                SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                String? savedDate = prefs.getString('latestPurchaseDate');
                if (savedDate != null &&
                    savedDate != latestPurchaseDate.toString()) {
                  slowCardApproval = false;
                }
              }
            });
          }
          if (e.code == '20') {
            slowCardApproval = true;
          }
        }
        if (slowCardApproval) {
          Purchases.addCustomerInfoUpdateListener((customerInfo) async {
            var entitlements = customerInfo.entitlements.all;
            debugPrint('entitlements*********************: $entitlements');
            if (entitlements.isNotEmpty) {
              var latestPurchaseDate =
                  entitlements.values.first.latestPurchaseDate;
              SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
              String? savedDate = prefs.getString('latestPurchaseDate');
              debugPrint(
                  'latestPurchaseDate*********************: $latestPurchaseDate');
              debugPrint('savedDate*********************: $savedDate');
              if (savedDate != null &&
                  savedDate != latestPurchaseDate.toString()) {
                if (customerInfo
                    .entitlements
                    .all[Platform.isIOS
                        ? dotenv.env['REVENUECAT_ENTITLEMENTS_APPLE']
                        : dotenv.env['REVENUECAT_ENTITLEMENTS_GOOGLE']]!
                    .isActive) {
                  isPurchasePending =
                      false; // Set isPurchasePending to false when a purchase is confirmed
                  ref
                      .read(purchaseInProgressProvider.notifier)
                      .setInProgress(false); // Add this line
                  final titleValue = getTitlePurchase(payload['title']);
                  final titleKoValue = getTitleKoPurchase(payload['title']);
                  ref.read(bonusEggsHistoryProvider).memberBonusAttend(
                        memberId: memberInfo.id!,
                        bonusEggQty: int.parse(numberOfEgg),
                        type: 1,
                        title: titleValue,
                        titleKo: titleKoValue,
                      );
                  // Create a new instance of MemberModel with the updated purchasedEggs value
                  if (memberInfo.id != null) {
                    final updatedMemberInfo = memberInfo.copyWith(
                        purchasedEggs:
                            memberInfo.purchasedEggs! + int.parse(numberOfEgg));
                    // Update memberInfo immediately after purchase is successful
                    ref
                        .read(memberInfoProvider.notifier)
                        .updateState(updatedMemberInfo);
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => ChargeUseHistoryScreen(
                                purchasedEgg: filteredItems[0]['id'],
                                purchaseSuccessful: true,
                              )),
                    ).then((value) => {
                          ref.refresh(memberObjByIdProvider(memberInfo.id)),
                          ref.refresh(memberObjByIdProvider(eggMember!.id)),
                          ref.refresh(memberObjProvider),
                          ref.refresh(memberInfoProvider),
                          ref.refresh(bonusEggsHistoryProvider),
                          ref.refresh(
                              memberObjByIdProvider(memberInfo.id ?? 0)),
                          ref.refresh(
                              usageEggHistoryFutureProvider(memberInfo.id!)),
                          ref.refresh(purchasedEggHistoryFutureProvider(
                              memberInfo.id!)),
                          ref.refresh(loadingProvider),
                        });
                    ref
                        .read(purchaseInProgressProvider.notifier)
                        .setInProgress(false);
                  }
                  debugPrint('Purchase successful########################');
                }
              }

              await prefs.setString(
                  'latestPurchaseDate', latestPurchaseDate.toString());
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }

I expected  “Slow test card, declines after a few minutes” will response status confirmed the   purchase declines.
